# iOS div dragging underneath slideout sidebar, but not on Android

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css, sidebar

For the sliding sidebar, we are using Sidr, and for the platform, we are using Ember (Discourse).

The images display the issue I'm talking about with respect to the same div behaving differently according to whether it's iOS (1st image), or Android (2nd image). Specifically, the main content div on iOS is able to be dragged/slide underneath the sidebar.

I have tried a whole array and variations of overflow: hidden -> overflow-y: auto, but these have not worked to prevent the div on iOS from sliding underneath.

I had also tried Sliderjs, with the same issue, so it must just be an iOS quirk...

[image: iOS behaviour: Notice how the div slides underneath the sidebar]

[image: Android behaviour: Notice how the divs are discrete]